# Анимация на Javascript не плавная

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему анимация не плавная?

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

function myAnimation() {
    let box = document.querySelector('.box'),
            boxWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).width),
            boxHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).height),
            elem = document.querySelector('.square'),
            elemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).width),
            elemHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).height),
            pos_top = 0,
            pos_left = 0,
            id = setInterval(frame, 100);

    function frame() {
        if(pos_top == 0 && pos_left == 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < (boxWidth - elemWidth); i++) {
                pos_left++;
                elem.style.left = pos_left + 'px';
            }
        } else if(pos_top == 0 && pos_left == 300) {
            for(let i = 0; i < (boxHeight - elemHeight); i++) {
                pos_top++;
                elem.style.top = pos_top + 'px';
            }
        } else if(pos_top == 300 && pos_left == 300) {
            for(let i = 0; i < (boxWidth - elemWidth); i++) {
                pos_left--;
                elem.style.left = pos_left + 'px';
            }
        } else if(pos_top == 300 && pos_left == 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < (boxHeight - elemHeight); i++) {
                pos_top--;
                elem.style.top = pos_top + 'px';
            }
        } 
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', myAnimation);

});
```

https://codepen.io/FOXY_FO/pen/wEgmry

Comment: потому что анимация отрабатывает со скоростью обработки цикла браузером, Вы не успеваете заметить ее

Comment: Максим Ленский, добавлял, он начинал двигаться по центру, а не по бокам

Comment: Дмытрык, я это понимаю, но как это исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не плавная она потому, что вы каждый кадр вызываете функцию `frame`, в ней уже в цикле передвигаете квадрат до следующего угла, да только цикл выполнится в этом же кадре.
Поэтому когда браузер снова решит отрисовать кадр, ваш квадрат уже в другом углу. И так каждый раз

Чтобы исправить, просто уберите цикл и поменяйте условия

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

  function myAnimation() {
    btn.removeEventListener('click', myAnimation);; // один раз нажали и хватит:)
    let box = document.querySelector('.box'),
      boxWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).width),
      boxHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).height),
      elem = document.querySelector('.square'),
      elemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).width),
      elemHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).height),
      pos_top = 0,
      pos_left = 0,
      id = setInterval(frame, 16);

    function frame() {
      if(pos_top == 0 && pos_left < 300) {
        pos_left++;
        elem.style.left = pos_left + 'px';
      } else if(pos_top < 300 && pos_left == 300) {
        pos_top++;
        elem.style.top = pos_top + 'px';
      } else if(pos_top == 300 && pos_left > 0) {
        pos_left--;
        elem.style.left = pos_left + 'px';
      } else if(pos_top > 0 && pos_left == 0) {
        pos_top--;
        elem.style.top = pos_top + 'px';
      }
    }
  }

  btn.addEventListener('click', myAnimation);
});
```

```css
button:focus, input:focus {
  outline:  none;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid #FF646E;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #7C73FF;
}

.animate {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #D0FF00;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="animate">Animate</button>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: +1. Нажмите на кнопку несколько раз :).

Comment: @Igor ну у ТС тоже нет фильтрация на клик, так что я не стал про это писать)

Comment: Подозреваю, что это будет следующий вопрос ТС.

Comment: @Igor исправил)